# How to check Internet status android

Tags: java, android, httprequest, ping, connectivity

I m novice in Android . Please help me to solve my problem ! my app is working online and offline ! when Wifi is connected but there is no internet connection app must be switched to offline mode. and for offline mode i was using this code:

```
public class Connectivity {

public static boolean isOnline() {
    try {
        Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 -W1 www.google.com");
        int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
        boolean reachable = (returnVal == 0);
        return reachable;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_online_chat,container,false);

    WebView webView =(WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("url");
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout =(RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.llout);
    Button btnConnect =(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnRetry);


    if (Connectivity.isOnline()){
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    return v;





}
```

But its not working with some phone models.
I have been suffering with this problem for 2 weeks already. I've tried everything on this website (all methods) but it doesn't work for me . What i need to do ???

Comment: Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out?noredirect=1&lq=1, it may be of help. It mentions lack of support for your method on some devices.

Comment: i was trying that code . but it doesnt work too